# Retro lambda Configuration issue on Android Studio 2.0 Beta 6

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, rx-java, rx-android, retrolambda

I have just started with Rx-Android and Retro Lambda. I am creating a hello world project. I followed the instruction but project doesn't compile.

I got an error

Error:Execution failed for task ':mobile:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Javajdk1.8.0_65/bin/javac''

I am running window's 10 machine having following configuration
Android Studio          : 2.0 Beta 6
Gradle Version          : 2.10
Android Plugin version  : 2.0.0-beta6

 **Gradle Scripts**

-----------------Top Level Build.gradle---------------

```html
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta6'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.3.0-beta4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

---

-------------------------  Modules Build.Gradle ----------------------

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.findit.hellorxjava"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    wearApp project(':wear')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'

    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.3.0'
}
```

Stack Trace on Debugging

```html
14:13:04.515 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
14:13:04.515 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
14:13:04.515 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
14:13:04.516 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
14:13:04.516 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':mobile:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
14:13:04.516 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Javajdk1.8.0_65\/bin/javac''
14:13:04.516 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
14:13:04.516 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
14:13:04.516 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':mobile:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
14:13:04.517 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
14:13:04.517 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
14:13:04.517 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
14:13:04.517 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
14:13:04.517 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
14:13:04.517 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
14:13:04.517 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
14:13:04.517 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
14:13:04.518 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
14:13:04.518 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
14:13:04.518 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
14:13:04.518 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
14:13:04.518 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
14:13:04.518 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
14:13:04.519 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
14:13:04.519 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
14:13:04.519 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
14:13:04.519 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
14:13:04.519 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
14:13:04.519 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
14:13:04.520 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
14:13:04.520 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
14:13:04.520 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
14:13:04.520 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
14:13:04.520 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
14:13:04.520 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
14:13:04.521 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
14:13:04.521 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
14:13:04.521 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
14:13:04.521 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
14:13:04.521 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
14:13:04.521 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
14:13:04.521 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
14:13:04.521 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
14:13:04.521 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
14:13:04.521 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:46)
14:13:04.522 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
14:13:04.522 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
14:13:04.522 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
14:13:04.522 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
14:13:04.522 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
14:13:04.523 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
14:13:04.523 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
14:13:04.523 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
14:13:04.523 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
14:13:04.523 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
14:13:04.523 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
14:13:04.523 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
14:13:04.524 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
14:13:04.524 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
14:13:04.524 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
14:13:04.524 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
14:13:04.524 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
14:13:04.524 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
14:13:04.524 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
14:13:04.524 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
14:13:04.525 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
14:13:04.525 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
14:13:04.525 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
14:13:04.525 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
14:13:04.525 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
14:13:04.525 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
14:13:04.525 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
14:13:04.525 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
14:13:04.525 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
14:13:04.526 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
14:13:04.526 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
14:13:04.526 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
14:13:04.526 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
14:13:04.526 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
14:13:04.526 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
14:13:04.526 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Javajdk1.8.0_65\/bin/javac''
14:13:04.527 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:197)
14:13:04.527 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.failed(DefaultExecHandle.java:327)
14:13:04.527 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:86)
14:13:04.527 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  ... 2 more
14:13:04.527 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start 'C:\Program Files\Javajdk1.8.0_65\/bin/javac'
14:13:04.527 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
14:13:04.527 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WindowsProcessLauncher.start(WindowsProcessLauncher.java:22)
14:13:04.527 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcessLauncher.start(WrapperProcessLauncher.java:36)
14:13:04.528 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:68)
14:13:04.528 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  ... 2 more
14:13:04.528 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Javajdk1.8.0_65\/bin/javac" (in directory "D:\Experimental_Workspace\HelloRxJava\mobile"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
14:13:04.528 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
14:13:04.528 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  ... 5 more
14:13:04.528 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
14:13:04.528 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  ... 6 more
14:13:04.528 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
14:13:04.528 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
14:13:04.528 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
```

I don't know what went wrong? Please help me?

Comment: does it fail if you compile from command line?

Comment: Getting same error while building from command line. Stack track is same as above

Answer (score 1):

From your stacktrace:

> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Javajdk1.8.0_65/bin/javac''

Looks to me that your JAVA_HOME/PATH environment variable is not correctly set.

It should be something like this:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\javac

Comment: Noting the back-slash between `Java` and `jdk1.8.0_65`.